# Simple logistic regression in MatLab - beginner help required

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do a simple logistic regression analysis in MatLab.

```
X = [103.4843 103.4843 100.3871 101.8535 101.7658 101.9658];
Y = [120.9189 107.3617 122.5506 96.9701 101.9798 118.3035];
B = mnrfit(X,Y)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
If Y is a column vector, it must contain positive integer category numbers.
```

I'm not sure why. Can someone please help?! Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `mnrfit`? Do the examples provided there work for you?

Comment: Yes @David, I have tried it with the examples given and it works fine... Thanks

Comment: Building on what David has said, this is an important line to read when looking at the documentation:  `B = mnrfit(X,Y);` ... Alternatively, `Y` can be an `N` element column vector of scalar integers from 1 to `K` indicating the value of the response for each observation, and all sample sizes are taken to be 1.  So... given this information, does your data in the code you showed us fit how to use `mnrfit`?

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng - yes, from what I understand of the documentation, I think my data should work with this code...

Comment: Well obviously not.  Your `Y` variable is required to be scalar integers, yet in your code they are floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Pls read the documentation of mnrfit:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html#btmaowv-Y

Try use table and then let Y be the categorical array.

For example, my code:

```
%% Multinomial Logistic Regression

% read csv file and create table
% header = {'Year','Abortion','DowJones','Incarceration','Crime_Rate'};

data = csvread("E:\code\project\regression.csv",1,0);
year = data(:,1);
abortion = data(:,2);
dowjones = data(:,3);
incarceration = data(:,4);
crime_rate = data(:,5);
T = table(year,abortion,dowjones,incarceration,crime_rate);

% multinomial logistic regression
X = [abortion,dowjones,incarceration];
Y = categorical(crime_rate);

% B: coefficicent estimates
% dev: deviance of the fit
% stats: model statistics

[B,dev,stats] = mnrfit(X,Y,'Model','ordinal','link','logit');
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is used when dependent variable namely variable y is a 
binary number 0 or 1. Nominal Logistic Regression is quite wide as dependent 
variable could take more than 2 values, but they have to be consecutive natural 
numbers. For example Y = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
X, the independent variable doesn't have this restriction it can be any reel 
number.

To use mnrfit  proceed  as follow

```
X = [103.4843 103.4843 100.3871 101.8535 101.7658 101.9658];
if X > 103 --> X large --> translated to Y = 2
if 101 < X < 103 --> X medium --> translated to Y = 1
if X < 101 --> X small--> translated to Y = 0
```

There are 3 categories : O small, 1 medium, 2 large
Following the logic above

Y = [2 2 0 1 1 1]

Type the following code in matalb and check

```
X = [103.4843 103.4843 100.3871 101.8535 101.7658 101.9658];
Y = [2 2 0 1 1 1];
Y = categorical(Y);
B = mnrfit(X,Y);
```

According to your Y data format, I suggest you use polynomial linear regression 
model instead of logistic regression since your Y values are not discrete.

Polynomial linear regression

```
X = [103.4843 103.4843 100.3871 101.8535 101.7658 101.9658];
Y = [120.9189 107.3617 122.5506 96.9701 101.9798 118.3035];

B = polyfit(X,Y,length(X)-1);
```